# Is it safe to perform a trick after the ramp at Rainbow Road?

Tags: mario-kart-wii

I have read a few website pages and watched some videos on Rainbow Road (Wii) and some say there is a risk of falling off the track if you perform a trick. Is this true, and if it is, how can I avoid it?

Comment: Although to answer your question better (with no real backup evidence, hence the comment answer) your best bet is just to angle yourself towards the middle of the road after the ramp, even a little more toward the top. It's really just a skill-based thing (hence the first joke comment)

Comment: I've never had trouble doing tricks in Rainbow Road. Normal driving on Rainbow Road is more perilous.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, it is safe, if your talking about the one right after the steep downhill section with boost panels. I personoly feel that all ramps on Rainbow road are safe.

Answer (score -1):

All tricks on MKW's Rainbow Road are safe at the correct angles and speed.